# MFC: Dialog PreTranslateMessage() WM_KEYDOWN not seeing VK_DELETE?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a weird one where I get all the other virtual keys but `VK_DELETE` is not received?  This is an MFC App and based on a `CDialogEx`.  I check for it in the `PreTranslateMessage()`

```
    if (pMsg->wParam==VK_SPACE) {
      // do my stuff - WORKS!
    }
    else if (pMsg->wParam==VK_INSERT) {
      // do my stuff - WORKS!
      draw=true;
    }
    else if (pMsg->wParam==VK_DELETE) {
      // do my stuff - NEVER RECEIVED!!
    }
    else ... etc ...
```

I copy/pasted above from code to ensure not something in the if statements I'm blind to see.

Any Ideas?

TIA!!

Comment: Not wishing to sound insulting, but have you checked (in a text editor, for example) that your delete key does actually work?

Comment: yes, it works, use it here and everywhere.  also tried the one on the numeric key pad, still no breakpoint and no action.  Searching the project for VK_DELETE found it's an accelerator for something else (that is not active/shown), but so where F6 and F7, so I tried VK_F6 and that worked fine, so not related to that.

Comment: Hmm. I tried in one of my project, inserting code to intercept VK_DELETE and VK_SPACE (giving different beeps), and it works fine. (I have a dialogue class derived from CDialogEx that already overrides `PreTranslateMessage()` and handles `WM_KEYDOWN` for other keys.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so finding `VK_DELETE` was an accelerator and `VK_F6` was as well, using `VK_F6` worked, but then looking closer at the accelerator `VK_F6` had `CONTROL`, removing that so acts like `VK_DELETE` has the same issue so these type of problems has to do with accelerators.

The workaround I used was to add a disable option so that the `TranslateAccelerator()` call would not be done from the `PretranslateMessage()` of the other main window.  This allowed the key pressed to be sent through to the dialog.